# Shopify store background video didn't show on mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, shopify

Hi I have a website build on Shopify, I want to have a nice background video, so I write the code on slidshow.liquid file, the background video works fine on normal size browser, but when it viewed on mobile device, I can't see the background video, instead, it left a lot blank space.

The core code as follows:

```
{% if section.settings.displayBGVOrNot == true %}
  <div id="videoSection" class="background-video">
    <video playinline autoplay muted loop id="bgvid">
      <source src="{{ section.settings.background_video_url }}" type="video/webm">
    </video>
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% javascript %}
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var viewPointHeight = $(window).height();
    var viewPointWeight = $(window).width();
    $('.background-video').css('height', viewPointHeight - 40 + 'px');
    $('.background-video').css('width', viewPointWeight + 'px');
  });
  $(window).resize($.debounce(250,
    function() {
      var viewPointHeight = $(window).height();
      var viewPointWeight = $(window).width();
      $('.background-video').css('height', viewPointHeight - 40 + 'px');
      $('.background-video').css('width', viewPointWeight + 'px');
    })
  );
{% endjavascript %}

      #videoSection {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  video#bgvid {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 0;
      background-size: cover;
  }
  @media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    html {
         background: url(polina.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
    #bgvid {
        display: none;
    }
  }
```

The website is https://opusion.com/, you can view it on mobile device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. In your CSS there is a condition (media query) for smaller devices.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {..
```

That means, "do the following for all devices smaller then 800px". In that block follows a `display: none` for `#bgvid`, which is the id of your video container. You just could remove it to show the video on mobile devices, too.

BUT:
Have in mind that's not bad practice to show videos to mobile customer. The bandwidth is much more limited and depending on your video implementation it could be that the device isn't able to play the video because the codec or the video format is not supported.